# Email alert to contain full details of list item created

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have created a basic workflow that sends an email to a specific person when a new item is created. 
However, this person wants all the details of that list item in the email. (They don't want to open the list in SharePoint).

They use to get something that looks like this:
[image]

That workflow mysteriously broke a couple of months ago and I'm now trying to recreate it. The best I can get to is something like this. 
[image]

I'm doing this through Flow. When I set up an alert it sends out a blank email - all it says is a new list item was created. (And that doesn't seem to even work!)

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a flow from blank and select the trigger, "When an item is created" using SharePoint Connector.
Enter your Site address and list name.
Create a new step and select Office 365 Outlook then "Send an email" action.
Enter the email address of the user who needs to get the mail and subject.
Then in the body, Type the words you need and input corresponding dynamic content in front of each word.
However, ensure you select the option IsHtml to be Yes and in your body, type the mail in form of html i.e If you need to bolden the wordings you need to put it in `<b> </b>` tag and to have a line break you need to put a `<br/>` tag